# Retrieving data from database using EF Core takes too long

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm working on an API project using ASP.NET Core and EF Core 6. I have created a relational database using the `Code-First` approach. The problem is that when I try to get all data in the table `PmSchedules` from the database, it takes too long while I have only 20 records in the table.

When I have 30 records in that table, PostMan throws an error and says:

> Error: Maximum response size reached

Some of the properties related to that table are:

```
public class PmSchedule
{
    [Key]
    public long PmScheduleId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public long ScheduleNumber { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime ScheduledStartDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime ScheduledEndDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string MainFileName { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string? UploadedFileName { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? CompletionDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string? Status { get; set; }

    //Navigation properties
    public virtual CostCenter CostCenter { get; set; }
    public virtual ServiceType ServiceType { get; set; }
    //For Adding two foreinkeys
    [Required]
    public int MainUploaderId { get; set; }
    public User MainUploader { get; set; }
    public int? UploaderId { get; set; }
    public User Uploader { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int WorkCenterId { get; set; }
    public WorkCenter WorkCenter { get; set; }
}

public class WorkCenter
{
    [Key]
    public int WorkCenterId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public WorkCenters Work_Center { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    //Navigation propery
    public virtual List<UserWorkCenter>? UserWorkCenters { get; set; }
    public virtual List<PmSchedule>? PmSchedules { get; set; }
    public virtual List<PmDataSet>? PmDataSets { get; set; }
}

public enum WorkCenters
{
    Electrical,
    Mechanical
}

public class ServiceType
{
    [Key]
    public int ServiceTypeId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; } = true;

    //Navigation properties
    public virtual List<PmDataSet>? PmDataSets { get; set; }
    public virtual List<PmSchedule>? PmSchedules { get; set; }
}

public class CostCenter
{
    [Key]
    public int CostCenterId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; } = true;


    //Navigation properties
    public virtual List<PmDataSet>? PmDataSets { get; set; }
    public virtual List<PmSchedule>? PmSchedules { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Equipment>? Equipments { get; set; }
    public virtual List<UserCostCenter>? UserCostCenters { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using following code to produce the response:

```
var pmSchedule = await _sqlServerContext.PmSchedules
                                        .Include(x => x.CostCenter)
                                        .Include(x => x.ServiceType)
                                        .Include(x => x.WorkCenter)
                                        .ToListAsync();

if (pmSchedule.Count > 0)
{
    return Ok(pmSchedule);
}

return NoContent();
```

How can I fix this problem?

**Update 1:**

The API response for **only two** database entries are:

```
[
{
    "pmScheduleId": 2,
    "scheduleNumber": 100,
    "scheduledStartDate": "2022-06-22T00:00:00",
    "scheduledEndDate": "2022-07-05T00:00:00",
    "mainFileName": "2022-7-9-808ab30a-889a-4890-82b3-67e6d06da7c0.docx",
    "uploadedFileName": null,
    "completionDate": null,
    "status": "Registered",
    "costCenter": {
        "costCenterId": 2,
        "title": "USA",
        "isActive": true,
        "pmDataSets": null,
        "pmSchedules": [
            null,
            {
                "pmScheduleId": 3,
                "scheduleNumber": 100,
                "scheduledStartDate": "2022-06-22T00:00:00",
                "scheduledEndDate": "2022-07-05T00:00:00",
                "mainFileName": "2022-7-9-1fd2a4c8-0607-4258-beed-81f043c4fb5f.docx",
                "uploadedFileName": null,
                "completionDate": null,
                "status": "Registered",
                "costCenter": null,
                "serviceType": {
                    "serviceTypeId": 1,
                    "title": "Monthly",
                    "isActive": true,
                    "pmDataSets": null,
                    "pmSchedules": [
                        null,
                        null
                    ]
                },
                "mainUploaderId": 1,
                "mainUploader": null,
                "uploaderId": null,
                "uploader": null,
                "workCenterId": 1,
                "workCenter": {
                    "workCenterId": 1,
                    "work_Center": 0,
                    "isActive": true,
                    "userWorkCenters": null,
                    "pmSchedules": [
                        null,
                        null
                    ],
                    "pmDataSets": null
                }
            }
        ],
        "equipments": null,
        "userCostCenters": null
    },
    "serviceType": {
        "serviceTypeId": 1,
        "title": "Monthly",
        "isActive": true,
        "pmDataSets": null,
        "pmSchedules": [
            null,
            {
                "pmScheduleId": 3,
                "scheduleNumber": 100,
                "scheduledStartDate": "2022-06-22T00:00:00",
                "scheduledEndDate": "2022-07-05T00:00:00",
                "mainFileName": "2022-7-9-1fd2a4c8-0607-4258-beed-81f043c4fb5f.docx",
                "uploadedFileName": null,
                "completionDate": null,
                "status": "Registered",
                "costCenter": {
                    "costCenterId": 2,
                    "title": "USA",
                    "isActive": true,
                    "pmDataSets": null,
                    "pmSchedules": [
                        null,
                        null
                    ],
                    "equipments": null,
                    "userCostCenters": null
                },
                "serviceType": null,
                "mainUploaderId": 1,
                "mainUploader": null,
                "uploaderId": null,
                "uploader": null,
                "workCenterId": 1,
                "workCenter": {
                    "workCenterId": 1,
                    "work_Center": 0,
                    "isActive": true,
                    "userWorkCenters": null,
                    "pmSchedules": [
                        null,
                        null
                    ],
                    "pmDataSets": null
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "mainUploaderId": 1,
    "mainUploader": null,
    "uploaderId": null,
    "uploader": null,
    "workCenterId": 1,
    "workCenter": {
        "workCenterId": 1,
        "work_Center": 0,
        "isActive": true,
        "userWorkCenters": null,
        "pmSchedules": [
            null,
            {
                "pmScheduleId": 3,
                "scheduleNumber": 100,
                "scheduledStartDate": "2022-06-22T00:00:00",
                "scheduledEndDate": "2022-07-05T00:00:00",
                "mainFileName": "2022-7-9-1fd2a4c8-0607-4258-beed-81f043c4fb5f.docx",
                "uploadedFileName": null,
                "completionDate": null,
                "status": "Registered",
                "costCenter": {
                    "costCenterId": 2,
                    "title": "USA",
                    "isActive": true,
                    "pmDataSets": null,
                    "pmSchedules": [
                        null,
                        null
                    ],
                    "equipments": null,
                    "userCostCenters": null
                },
                "serviceType": {
                    "serviceTypeId": 1,
                    "title": "Monthly",
                    "isActive": true,
                    "pmDataSets": null,
                    "pmSchedules": [
                        null,
                        null
                    ]
                },
                "mainUploaderId": 1,
                "mainUploader": null,
                "uploaderId": null,
                "uploader": null,
                "workCenterId": 1,
                "workCenter": null
            }
        ],
        "pmDataSets": null
    }
},
{
    "pmScheduleId": 3,
    "scheduleNumber": 100,
    "scheduledStartDate": "2022-06-22T00:00:00",
    "scheduledEndDate": "2022-07-05T00:00:00",
    "mainFileName": "2022-7-9-1fd2a4c8-0607-4258-beed-81f043c4fb5f.docx",
    "uploadedFileName": null,
    "completionDate": null,
    "status": "Registered",
    "costCenter": {
        "costCenterId": 2,
        "title": "USA",
        "isActive": true,
        "pmDataSets": null,
        "pmSchedules": [
            {
                "pmScheduleId": 2,
                "scheduleNumber": 100,
                "scheduledStartDate": "2022-06-22T00:00:00",
                "scheduledEndDate": "2022-07-05T00:00:00",
                "mainFileName": "2022-7-9-808ab30a-889a-4890-82b3-67e6d06da7c0.docx",
                "uploadedFileName": null,
                "completionDate": null,
                "status": "Registered",
                "costCenter": null,
                "serviceType": {
                    "serviceTypeId": 1,
                    "title": "Monthly",
                    "isActive": true,
                    "pmDataSets": null,
                    "pmSchedules": [
                        null,
                        null
                    ]
                },
                "mainUploaderId": 1,
                "mainUploader": null,
                "uploaderId": null,
                "uploader": null,
                "workCenterId": 1,
                "workCenter": {
                    "workCenterId": 1,
                    "work_Center": 0,
                    "isActive": true,
                    "userWorkCenters": null,
                    "pmSchedules": [
                        null,
                        null
                    ],
                    "pmDataSets": null
                }
            },
            null
        ],
        "equipments": null,
        "userCostCenters": null
    },
    "serviceType": {
        "serviceTypeId": 1,
        "title": "Monthly",
        "isActive": true,
        "pmDataSets": null,
        "pmSchedules": [
            {
                "pmScheduleId": 2,
                "scheduleNumber": 100,
                "scheduledStartDate": "2022-06-22T00:00:00",
                "scheduledEndDate": "2022-07-05T00:00:00",
                "mainFileName": "2022-7-9-808ab30a-889a-4890-82b3-67e6d06da7c0.docx",
                "uploadedFileName": null,
                "completionDate": null,
                "status": "Registered",
                "costCenter": {
                    "costCenterId": 2,
                    "title": "USA",
                    "isActive": true,
                    "pmDataSets": null,
                    "pmSchedules": [
                        null,
                        null
                    ],
                    "equipments": null,
                    "userCostCenters": null
                },
                "serviceType": null,
                "mainUploaderId": 1,
                "mainUploader": null,
                "uploaderId": null,
                "uploader": null,
                "workCenterId": 1,
                "workCenter": {
                    "workCenterId": 1,
                    "work_Center": 0,
                    "isActive": true,
                    "userWorkCenters": null,
                    "pmSchedules": [
                        null,
                        null
                    ],
                    "pmDataSets": null
                }
            },
            null
        ]
    },
    "mainUploaderId": 1,
    "mainUploader": null,
    "uploaderId": null,
    "uploader": null,
    "workCenterId": 1,
    "workCenter": {
        "workCenterId": 1,
        "work_Center": 0,
        "isActive": true,
        "userWorkCenters": null,
        "pmSchedules": [
            {
                "pmScheduleId": 2,
                "scheduleNumber": 100,
                "scheduledStartDate": "2022-06-22T00:00:00",
                "scheduledEndDate": "2022-07-05T00:00:00",
                "mainFileName": "2022-7-9-808ab30a-889a-4890-82b3-67e6d06da7c0.docx",
                "uploadedFileName": null,
                "completionDate": null,
                "status": "Registered",
                "costCenter": {
                    "costCenterId": 2,
                    "title": "USA",
                    "isActive": true,
                    "pmDataSets": null,
                    "pmSchedules": [
                        null,
                        null
                    ],
                    "equipments": null,
                    "userCostCenters": null
                },
                "serviceType": {
                    "serviceTypeId": 1,
                    "title": "Monthly",
                    "isActive": true,
                    "pmDataSets": null,
                    "pmSchedules": [
                        null,
                        null
                    ]
                },
                "mainUploaderId": 1,
                "mainUploader": null,
                "uploaderId": null,
                "uploader": null,
                "workCenterId": 1,
                "workCenter": null
            },
            null
        ],
        "pmDataSets": null
    }
}
```

]

Comment: Probably circular references in JSON.

Comment: If you work on API project, it is good style to return DTO not Database Model.

Comment: @GertArnold I have used some FluentAPI codes and created the database successfully. How can I solve circular references?

Comment: I updated my question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

I used the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute in some of the properties causing circular reference in JSON. The problem is solved.

Answer (score -1):

why You marked all the string fields as [DataType(DataType.Text)]
That is the mistake. remove all [DataType(DataType.Text)] and add Length attribute. It should fix your issue.

Comment: Do you mean something like this `[MaxLength(100)]`?

Comment: I tested. Not solved.

Comment: I updated my question. Please have a look.